# Closing JFrame following MVC

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to close a frame using the dispose() method, in a action listener however it won't work.

```
public class LoginController implements ActionListener, Observer {

    private JTextField name;
    private JTextField password;
    private LoginPage login;

/// // LoginFrame f1 = new LoginFrame();
    public LoginController(JTextField name, JTextField Password, LoginPage login) {
        this.name = name;
        this.password = Password;
        this.login = login;

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        login.LoginPage();
        login.checkLogin(name.getText(), password.getText());
        //  dipose();
    }
}
```

I've tried creating the frame however this goes into loops.

Comment: "wont work" is not accurate. Further explain the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispose` is obviously not a method of your controller.  Nor is it a method of any component that your controller has direct access to.

The question you need to ask yourself, is it appropriate behavior for your controller to be closing anything.

You have no guarantee that that `LoginPane` actually exists within a context that you can or should dispose.  What if the `LoginPane` is actually part of a `CardLayout`, if you arbitrarily dispose of the `LoginPane`'s parent window, you've just killed off the application inappropriately.

It is dangerous and bad design to assume anything about other parts of the application in this way/

A better method is to either allow the `LoginPane` to fire an event or have the controller fire an event, on successful login and allow some other controller to make the choice on how it should react to it.

If you are hell bent on this course of action, you could use `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(Component)`.  This will pass back the `Window` that the `Component` resides.

```
SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(login).dispose();
```

I would, personally, also check for a `null` `Window`

Comment: dipose() method is for a JFrame I understand that, I wanted the actionListener to remove the frame using the dispose() method, when the button is clicked, in the controller class.

Comment: Yeah, and what part of that answer failed to lead you to been able to that.  Just because I think it's bad idea and design doesn't mean I've not provided a means to achieve that...

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate your answer, sorry for the badly worded reply. Thank you

Comment: Look at the second last line.  This should dispose of the parent `Window` that the `login` pane resides in.  This should achieve the result you are looking for